# what is the meaning of "peg out" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrases

what is the meaning of "peg out" in this sentence?
Some times i "peg out" on junk food.
I have tried many forums. but i did not get my answer.

Comment: Peg-out normally means 'to die'. I think you may have heard 'pig-out' as the answer says.

Answer (score 2):

Ive never heard that used before. Might you be confused with “pig” out?

To “pig out” means to overeat. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pig-out?q=Pig+out

Comment: Oh... thanks. You may be right. I just heard that sentence and I may be confusing the word "pig" with "peg".